# Creating Fixture Data for PostgreSQL with SqlAlchemy and Id's

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm trying to inject sample data into my database, and have created a fixture file that builds my model, and then merges the instance into the database. I'm using merge, because I want to be able to re-run the fixture without recreating the database, or truncating all my tables.

However, upon inspection of my Postgres table's sequence on primary key, my_items_id_seq shows the following after injecting 10 items:

```
       Sequence "public.my_items_id_seq"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | my_items_id_seq
 last_value    | bigint  | 1
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 0
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | t
```

How can I increase the last_value as I merge in fixture data?

[edit]

The outstanding issue here is that after injecting the data, I can't add items to the database without getting an IntegrityError from SqlAlchemy. This is due to PostgreSQL trying to insert my new instance with id 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first part of the answer](http://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2011/05/06/integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint/) came through reading a link about Django and PostgreSQL, where the author similarly attempted to feed migration data with indexes.

His solution was to grab the highest index, and then execute the following query:

```
alter sequence profile_billingaddress_id_seq restart with {id};
```

Through this, I discovered the proper keyword to the PostgreSQL documentation on [Sequence Manipulation Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-sequence.html). The preferred way to do this is to issue this query:

```
select setval('my_items_id_seq', {id})
```

... where {id} is obviously a placeholder for a real integer. It also came to my attention that last_value is just the last response from next_value. This is important because using setval instead of the alter sequence business above ensures that nextval provides an unused index. I.e. when using setval where id=10, nextval will return 11. When using the alter sequence command, if id=10, then nextval will also return 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making the effort to post your own answer! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was trying to insert fixtures for various different models.

The following little snippet from [postgresql's wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences) will do just what you want but for every sequence in your schema.

```
SELECT 'SELECT SETVAL(' ||
   quote_literal(quote_ident(PGT.schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(S.relname)) ||
   ', COALESCE(MAX(' ||quote_ident(C.attname)|| '), 1) ) FROM ' ||
   quote_ident(PGT.schemaname)|| '.'||quote_ident(T.relname)|| ';'
FROM pg_class AS S,
     pg_depend AS D,
     pg_class AS T,
     pg_attribute AS C,
     pg_tables AS PGT
WHERE S.relkind = 'S'
    AND S.oid = D.objid
    AND D.refobjid = T.oid
    AND D.refobjid = C.attrelid
    AND D.refobjsubid = C.attnum
    AND T.relname = PGT.tablename
ORDER BY S.relname;
```

It looks a bit magical but does precisely what the accepted answer suggests.